# advanced list comparison in C#

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I started comparing lists for my little project. So far I can compare if the same items exists, or one value of this item fits the same value of another lists item.
Atm Im comparing the names from two lists. I changed some code I found for my purpose.

```
public class TestResources
{
     public string Name;
     public int Amount;

     public TestResources(string name, int amount)
     {
          Name = name;
          Amount = amount;
     }
}

TestResources[] ListResInStock = { new TestResources("wood", 1000), new TestResources("stone", 1000), new TestResources("sand", 1000), new TestResources("water", 1000) };
TestResources[] ListResNeeded = { new TestResources("wood", 800), new TestResources("stone", 800), new TestResources("sand", 375) };

private bool ContainsResourceName(IEnumerable<TestResources> ListResNeeded, IEnumerable<TestResources> ListResInStock)
{
     bool result;

     var list1WithName = ListResNeeded.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
     var list2WithName = ListResInStock.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();

     result = !list1WithName.Except(list2WithName).Any();

     return result;
}
```

the function is called with:

```
Console.WriteLine("ListResInStock contains ListResNeeded:   ===> " + ContainsResourceName(ListResNeeded, ListResInStock) + " <===");    // True
Console.WriteLine("ListResNeeded contains ListResInStock:   ===> " + ContainsResourceName(ListResInStock, ListResNeeded) + " <===");    // False
```

Now I want to change it, so that it only returns true, if the name of the ressNeeded is there and the amount of ressInStock is >= the Amount of RessNeeded (for all resources of course).

Also If you could explain this part `var list1WithName = ListResNeeded.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();` In detail to me would be nice because im not 100% sure what it does.

I really appreciate your help :-)

Comment: The LINQ method `Except` works on primitive types by default with DefaultComparer, So you are projecting the list into a list of strings (Primitive type) and using the DefaultComparer, To pass in your own comparer implement the IComparer interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply

```
private bool ContainsResourceName(IEnumerable<TestResources> ListResNeeded, IEnumerable<TestResources> ListResInStock)
{
     return ListResNeeded.All(resNeeded => 
         ListResInStock.Any(resInStock => 
              resInStock.Name == resNeeded.Name && 
              resInStock.Amount >= resNeeded.Amount
         )
     );
}
```

To understand the meaning of `.Select`, `.All`, `.First` and many other functions of so called `IEnumerable` interface, you'd have to learn about lazy evaluation in C#, and there's too much to say.

`ListResNeeded.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();` and other operations with enumerators are easier to read from the end. So from the end: you make a list (of what?) of elements produced by `Select` function (what does it produce?) it takes a resource `s` and returns `s.Name` of it (where are these resources coming from?) from the list ListResNeeded.

Again, you have to read more about `IEnumerator` in C#, and about lazy evaluation in general. It's an inportant concept in programming.

P.S. And some warnings about the code you tried to use. What you do there:

```
var list1WithName = ListResNeeded.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
var list2WithName = ListResInStock.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

is making full copy of both arguments that were passed into the function (imagine these arrays would be much much bigger, what's the point of copying them?).

And there you make a **new** (third) list after traversing both of the previous completely, while what you actually look for is just a boolean answer.

```
result = !list1WithName.Except(list2WithName).Any();
```

You don't have to traverse both lists completely before you know that the answer is false. You just need to find a **first** resource that is missing and then stop the search (it's much much lighter)

Comment: You should be careful about nested linear searches. E.g. if I have two lists 50 and 50 long and two lists that are 100 and 100 long, it will not take twice as long, but 4 times as long to evaluate the 100 long lists. So the execution time can quickly explode.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer and optimizing the result!

Comment: @weston I agree, but there's not much you can do without changing the data structure

Comment: @Ineedhelpplease weston is right, you should also consider the proper data structure for storing your resources. Having everything in a list and then searching on them is like throwing everything in a pile and then trying to find a thousand needles in it

Comment: Well even inside this method, you can create efficiencies by copying one of the lists into a new `Dictionary`.

Comment: Which data structure do you suggest? some kind of database? Is there an easy way to learn how to implement and use it?